# How to make object optional in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

My app is crashing when value is nil how can I avoid this and make the cake["likes"] optional?

My Code

```
var likes = [[String:Any]]()

init(cake: [String: Any]){
    self.likes = (cake["likes"] as! [String:Any])["data"] as! [[String:Any]]

}
```

Comment: have a look [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/12/optionals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cake["likes"]` **is** optional. The standard way is using optional bindings.

```
var likes = [[String:Any]]()

init(cake: [String: Any]) {
    if let likes = cake["likes"] as? [String:Any],
       let data = likes["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
           self.likes = data
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I thought I cannot assign if condition on a init. Thanks again.

Comment: @NazmulHasan That are two different cases. The dictionary in the parameter is non-optional but might not contain the `likes` key. The strong type system of Swift encourages to avoid optionals as much as possible.

Comment: @vadian please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453747/parsing-array-of-json-inside-object-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
var likes = [[String:Any]]()
init(cake: [String: Any]?) {
  guard let likes = cake?["likes"] as? [String:Any],
   let data = likes["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}
       self.likes = data
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However Im getting expected member name or constructor call after type name. Why is this?

Comment: I just modified the answer

Comment: still getting the error besides the var likes: [[String:Any]]? "expected member name or constructor call after type name"

Comment: Making the `likes` array optional is a bad solution

Comment: Right Vadian, @Jearson. Can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use`Guard`

```
 var likes : [[String:Any]]?

    init(cake: [String: Any]?){
        guard let cakeV = cake,let likes = (cakeV["likes"] as? [String:Any]) ,let data = likes ["data"] as?  [[String:Any]] else {
           // IT is nil
            return
        }
        likes = data

}
```